# Error: Using $this when not in object context - generate pdf using dompdf laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-8, dompdf

I wanted to generate `pdf` of the `view` file `certificate_template` & store the generated pdf file in `public` with the filename `certificate.pdf` . Below is what i tried.I got stuck with the below errors too. Any help is much appreciated.

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF;
return PDF::loadView('certificate_template', $data)->stream();
//$file='certificate.pdf';
```

I've installed `dompdf` with `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`.

added the correct `providers` & `aliases` in `config\app.php`.

The above code gives me the error

> Error: Using $this when not in object context in file C:\wamp\abc\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-dompdf\src\PDF.php on line 133

so i tried the below code, then i get the error

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\wamp\www\abc\app\Http\Controllers\CertificatesController.php on line 415 and exactly 4 expected in file C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-dompdf\src\PDF.php on line 49

```
$pdf=new PDF;
return $pdf->loadView('certificate_template', $data);
```

**EDIT**

The below code saves pdf file but its in binary format. I wanted it to be storedin original format.How can i do that?

```
$pdf=app()->make(PDF::class); 
$pdf->loadView('certificate_template', $data); 
$pdf->save('certificate_template.pdf');
return $pdf;
```

Comment: Looking at the docs, it might be that you have imported the wrong class? The one mentioned in the example is ``use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf;`` (see the Facade namespace). See [doc](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#using).

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the imported class in the top of your controller, so just replace

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF;
```

with

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf;
```

Or simply

```
use PDF;
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('certificate_template', $data);
$pdf->save('certificate_template.pdf');
return $pdf;
```

Comment: gives the same error `ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\wamp\www\abc\app\Http\Controllers\CertificatesController.php on line 415 and exactly 4 expected in file C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-dompdf\src\PDF.php on line 49`

Answer (score 0):

All run well with example code. Check my way:

Set this content in `routes\web.php`:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    // return view('welcome');
    // Work1
    // $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    // $pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
    // return $pdf->stream();

    // Work2
    $data = [
        'text1'=>'<h1>Test</h1><div class="text-red">This line is red color</div>',
        'text2'=> 'Just text'
    ];
    return PDF::loadView('template_one', $data)->stream();
});
```

With sample text in `resources\views\template_one.blade.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Template One</title>

        <style>
            .text-red {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       This is my page of test!
       {!! $text1 !!}
       <br/>
       {{ $text2 }}
    </body>
</html>
```

You will get successful result!

**Update**

To get content file you can use follow code:

```
// Work3
$data = [
    'text1'=>'<h1>Test</h1><div class="text-red">This line is red color</div>',
    'text2'=> 'Just text'
];
$pdf = app('dompdf.wrapper');  
$pdf->loadView('template_one', $data); 
// To save content as your desire
return $pdf->output();
```